# Not work Every time PhoneStateListener Android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I have Developing Application of Full Caller Id. In that dynamic screen call at the time of Incoming call / After Missed Call. Now this is work one time. When i received call. Than after it is not work or Not call any dynamic screen at the time Incoming call/ Missed call.

---

I have very confuse about my problem.

```
switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.v("idle state", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
        // CALL_STATE_IDLE;

        if(ring == true && callReceived == true && CheckMissCall.isReject == true)
        {
            Intent inter = new Intent(c, callLog.class);
            inter.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);          
            c.startActivity(inter); 
        }
        if (ring == true && callReceived == false && CheckMissCall.isRunning== false) {

            Log.v("missed call", "Missed call from : " + incomingNumber);
            if(CheckMissCall.isShown)
            {
                c.stopService(new Intent(c, Unlock_hud.class));

            }

            flag = true;
            if (prefs.getBoolean("main_state", true))
            {
                Intent inter = new Intent(c, MissCall.class);
                inter.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                inter.putExtra("CellNumber", incomingNumber);
                c.startActivity(inter);
            }

        }



        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        callReceived = true;
        Log.v("call received", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK  " + incomingNumber);


        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        ring = true;

        // CALL_STATE_RINGING
        Log.v("call ringing", "CALL_STATE_RINGING  " + incomingNumber);
        Log.d("flags", "flags: " + flag);
        if (flag) {

            //cut = true;
            //flag = false;
            CheckMissCall call = new CheckMissCall(c);
            call.setName(incomingNumber);
            call.setNumber4Sms(incomingNumber);
            call.setContactPhoto();

            Log.d("main", "state ringing");
            //prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

            if (!prefs.getBoolean("main_state", false)) {

                return;
            }
        /*  if (!isScreenOn && CheckMissCall.isRunning) {

                return;
            }*/
            if (CheckMissCall.isRunning) {

                return;
            }
            else {
                Log.d("main", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE:  Unlock hud");
                Intent in = new Intent(c, Unlock_hud.class);
                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
                c.startService(in);

                // c.stopService(new Intent(c, Unlock_hud.class));
            }
        }
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because when any call comes your app goes into background, while for the first time when you receive  call your `MyPhoneStateListener` listens for the call and it ends..
now do one thing.. Run your code in `service` it will run in background and it will call your dynamic screen
in your main activity start service  for this i have used toggle button(to enable or disable service)

```
tgl_switch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tgl_switch.isChecked()){
                 startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogsService.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Logger Active",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogsService.class));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Logger Deactive",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});
```

for example i did this

```
public class LogsService extends Service {

  String name;
  String phNumber;
 String callType;
 String callDate;
 Date callDayTime;
 String callDuration;
 String dir ;
  String fileName;

boolean wasRinging=false, wasoffHook=false, wasidle=false;


private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
                 Log.d("ring ", "Detected");
                 wasRinging = true;
                // get the phone number 
           //     String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
           //     Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                wasoffHook=true;
         //       Toast.makeText(context, "hang up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
                wasidle=true;

           //   Toast.makeText(context, "IDLE STATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                     if((wasRinging && wasoffHook && wasidle)){
                      // this is received call event


                     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Incoming.class));


                       } else if(wasRinging && wasidle){

                          // this is missed call event

                               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MissCall.class));


                       }

                         wasidle = false;
                         wasoffHook = false;
                         wasRinging=false;
                   }                     
            }
        }



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 @Override
   public void onCreate() {


     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
     filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy() {

         unregisterReceiver(receiver);
     }

}
```

i used this code to get details of **last call** you can modify it in your way

Comment: me mara code ma kari joyu koi problem nathi taari activity check kar

Comment: bhai Received call cut karu tyare Error ave 6e. @jaimin

Comment: have aa code ma jyare received call cut karu tyare nai but cut karta pa6i jyare second time call ave tyare INCOMING CALL screen open thati nathi.

Comment: bhai ave taru logic lagav thodu

Comment: bhai atlu logic chalvine j karyu 6e. but aa time confuse thai gyo 6u. 2nd time aa screen km open nathi thati.?